# Monogame file can''t be opened

Tags: c#, monogame

I tried to install MonoGame in Visual Studio 2012. Everything is okay, but when I try to make a new project (called `MonoGame Content Project`), VS threw an Exception that says: `A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'Game Name'. The project file c:\user\user\appdata\local\temp\..\temp\GameName.csproj can't be opened.`

Comment: Just to be clear, which version of monogame are you trying to use? Have you tried using the NuGet package on a simple (console maybe) program?

Comment: First try 3.2, then 3.0